# Почему "not in" не работает в моем коде Python?

Tags: python

```
Pр = [69.52, 54.9, 4.4, 0, 58.15, 71.57, 54.9, 1, 3.5, 58.15, 11, 11, 4.95, 10.84, 14.7, 7.86, 23.7]
Список_количества_квартир = [26, 18, 0, 0, 0, 27, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Список_имен_панелей = ["ЩЭ", "ЩЭ", "БАУО", "Резерв", "АВР-1", "ЩЭ", "ЩЭ", "ЩУ1", "ЩС-Т1", "АВР-1", "ШУЛ-1", "ШУЛ-2", "БАУО", "ЩС-ДУ1", "ЩС-Н1", "ЩУ-Пн", "КРМ"]
Не_учитывается = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Pр_Аварийная = []
for n in range(len(Pр)):
    if Список_количества_квартир[n] == 0 and Не_учитывается[n] == 0 and "ЩС-ДУ" not in Список_имен_панелей[n] or "ЩС-Пн" not in Список_имен_панелей[n] or "ЩУ-Пн" not in Список_имен_панелей[n] or "JET" not in Список_имен_панелей[n] or "ШУЛ" not in Список_имен_панелей[n] or "ЩУЛ" not in Список_имен_панелей[n]: Pр_Аварийная.append(Pр[n])
    else: pass

print(Pр_Аварийная)
```

Результат: [69.52, 54.9, 4.4, 0, 58.15, 71.57, 54.9, 1, 3.5, 58.15, 11, 11, 4.95, 10.84, 14.7, 7.86, 23.7]
Хотя должен быть: [4.4, 1, 3.5, 4.95, 14.7]

Comment: Условие `X != A or X != B`, где `X` - переменная, а `A` и `B` - разные константы, истинно при любых значениях `X`. Сформулируйте своё условие словами, по коду вообще не понятно, чего вы хотите добиться

Comment: Если разбираться как разобрался mrEvgenX ниже, то все станет понятно!

Comment: "теперь все работает! Только не понял почему? – NurJ"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`not in` работает хорошо. Все дело в составлении условия.

Все `or` в условии нужно заменить на `and`. Тогда вывод программы получается желаемый.

**Почему?** Объясняю так, как понял задачу.

Обозначим условия буквами для краткости

`"ЩС-ДУ" in Список_имен_панелей[n]` как А (без `not`!!!)

`"ЩС-Пн" in Список_имен_панелей[n]` - Б

итд.

тогда `not А` - это `"ЩС-ДУ" not in Список_имен_панелей[n]`, то, что нужно.

Нас интересует, судя по коду, чтобы ни одно из условий (ни А, ни Б, ни В...) не были верны.

Тогда получается:

`not A and not Б and not В...`

Comment: Спасибо теперь все работает! Только не понял почему?

Comment: Тут уже дело не в python, а более фундаментальных штуках. В интернете можно найти много чего интересного по запросу "Булева алгебра". И в таких сложных услвиях очень легко запутаться и потерять суть. Нужно либо пытаться упростить, либо проверять код на соответствие исходным намерениям.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы неверно составили условие.

У вас `A and B or C1 or C2...`

Нужно `A and B and (C1 or C2 or...)`

Думаю есть проблема с семантикой. Скорее всего вы имели в виду такое

```
badList=["Щупн", "JET",...] 

Далее в условии

A and B and Список_имен_панелей[n] not in badList
```

Основная проблема в непонимании логических операций

А and В - логическое И, истинно когда оба истинны

А or B - логическое ИЛИ, истинно когда хотя бы одно истинно.

Поэтому когда вы пишите A and B and (C or D), то условие выполнится, если хотя бы одно из С или D истинно.

Comment: Скобки поставил, но все равно результат не правильный, почему?

Comment: Почему вы ищете ЩСДУ только в конкретном элементе списка?

Comment: Чтобы добавить в новый список элемент из другого списка, с той же нумерацией

Comment: Смотрите: для 7.86 получаем 0, 0 JET не равен Щупн. По вашему условию все подходит.

Comment: Почему неправильный? Проверьте условия - всё по вашим условиям. Или вам надо, чтобы не "ЩУЛ", а "ШУЛ-1" отсеивался, например?

Comment: Мне надо чтобы было условие: если A = 0 и B = 0 и (C нету в D или E нету в F), и чтобы все три условия выполнялись

Comment: Добавил пример в ответ